# Spark: Performant way to find top n values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a large dataset and I would like to find rows with n highest values.

```
id, count
id1, 10
id2, 15
id3, 5
...
```

The only method I can think of is using `row_number` without partition like

```scala
val window = Window.orderBy(desc("count"))

df.withColumn("row_number", row_number over window).filter(col("row_number") <= n)
```

but this is in no way performant when the data contains millions or billions of rows because it pushes the data into one partition and I get OOM.

Has anyone managed to come up with a performant solution?

Comment: Updated the answer as promised.

Comment: Thanks @thebluephantom. Will try out the solutions mentioned in the answers and revert back in a while.

Comment: The point is I avoid OOM if you partition correctly.

Comment: @igeass what solution did you finally use ? What was the most performant for your case ? I'm curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I see two methods to improve your algorithm performance. First is to use [`sort`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#sort(sortExprs:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BT%5D) and [`limit`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#limit(n:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BT%5D) to retrieve the top n rows. The second is to develop your custom [`Aggregator`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-udf-aggregate.html#aggregator-in-buf-out).**

### Sort and Limit method

You sort your dataframe and then you take the first `n` rows:

```scala
val n: Int = ???

import org.apache.spark.functions.sql.desc

df.orderBy(desc("count")).limit(n)
```

Spark optimizes this kind of transformations sequence by first performing sort on each partition, taking first `n` rows on each partition, retrieving it on a final partition and reperforming sort and taking final first `n` rows. You can check this by executing `explain()` on transformations. You get the following execution plan:

```
== Physical Plan ==
TakeOrderedAndProject(limit=3, orderBy=[count#8 DESC NULLS LAST], output=[id#7,count#8])
+- LocalTableScan [id#7, count#8]
```

And by looking how `TakeOrderedAndProject` step is executed in [limit.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/limit.scala) in Spark's source code (case class `TakeOrderedAndProjectExec`, method `doExecute`).

### Custom Aggregator method

For custom aggregator, you create an `Aggregator` that will populate and update an ordered array of top `n` rows.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder

import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

case class Record(id: String, count: Int)

case class TopRecords(limit: Int) extends Aggregator[Record, ArrayBuffer[Record], Seq[Record]] {

  def zero: ArrayBuffer[Record] = ArrayBuffer.empty[Record]

  def reduce(topRecords: ArrayBuffer[Record], currentRecord: Record): ArrayBuffer[Record] = {
    val insertIndex = topRecords.lastIndexWhere(p => p.count > currentRecord.count)
    if (topRecords.length < limit) {
      topRecords.insert(insertIndex + 1, currentRecord)
    } else if (insertIndex < limit - 1) {
      topRecords.insert(insertIndex + 1, currentRecord)
      topRecords.remove(topRecords.length - 1)
    }
    topRecords
  }

  def merge(topRecords1: ArrayBuffer[Record], topRecords2: ArrayBuffer[Record]): ArrayBuffer[Record] = {
    val merged = ArrayBuffer.empty[Record]
    while (merged.length < limit && (topRecords1.nonEmpty || topRecords2.nonEmpty)) {
      if (topRecords1.isEmpty) {
        merged.append(topRecords2.remove(0))
      } else if (topRecords2.isEmpty) {
        merged.append(topRecords1.remove(0))
      } else if (topRecords2.head.count < topRecords1.head.count) {
        merged.append(topRecords1.remove(0))
      } else {
        merged.append(topRecords2.remove(0))
      }
    }
    merged
  }

  def finish(reduction: ArrayBuffer[Record]): Seq[Record] = reduction

  def bufferEncoder: Encoder[ArrayBuffer[Record]] = ExpressionEncoder[ArrayBuffer[Record]]

  def outputEncoder: Encoder[Seq[Record]] = ExpressionEncoder[Seq[Record]]

}
```

And then you apply this aggregator on your dataframe, and flatten the aggregation result:

```scala
val n: Int = ???

import sparkSession.implicits._

df.as[Record].select(TopRecords(n).toColumn).flatMap(record => record)
```

### Method comparison

To compare those two methods, let's say we want to take top `n` rows of a dataframe that is distributed on `p` partitions, each partition having around `k` records. So dataframe has size `p·k`. Which gives the following complexity (subject to errors):

| method | total number of operations | memory consumption (on executor) | memory consumption (on final executor) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Current code** | `O(p·k·log(p·k))` | -- | `O(p·k)` |
| **Sort and Limit** | `O(p·k·log(k) + p·n·log(p·n))` | `O(k)` | `O(p·n)` |
| **Custom Aggregator** | `O(p·k)` | `O(k) + O(n)` | `O(p·n)` |

So regarding number of operations, **Custom Aggregator** is the most performant. However, this method is by far the most complex and implies lots of serialization/deserialization so it may be less performant than **Sort and Limit** on certain case.

### Conclusion

You have two methods to efficiently take top `n` rows, **Sort and Limit** and **Custom Aggregator**. To select which one to use, you should benchmark those two methods with your real dataframe. If after benchmarking **Sort and Limit** is a bit slower than **Custom aggregator**, I would select **Sort and Limit** as its code is a lot easier to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

1. Convert to rdd
2. mapPartitions sorting the data, take N
3. Convert to df
4. Then sort and rank and take top N. Unlikely you will have OOM

**Actual example, slightly updated, roll your own approach for posterity.**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DoubleType, IntegerType, StringType, StructField, StructType}

// 1. Create data
val data = Seq(("James ","","Smith","36636","M",33000),
                 ("Michael ","Rose","","40288","M",14000),
                 ("Robert ","","Williams","42114","M",40),
                 ("Robert ","","Williams","42114","M",540),
                 ("Robert ","","Zeedong","42114","M",40000000),
                 ("Maria ","Anne","Jones","39192","F",300),
                 ("Maria ","Anne","Vangelis","39192","F",1300),
                 ("Jen","Mary","Brown","","F",-1))

val columns = Seq("firstname","middlename","lastname","dob","gender","val")
val df = data.toDF(columns:_*)
//df.show()

//2. Any number of partitions, and sort that partition. Combiner function like Hadoop.
val df2 = df.repartition(1000,col("lastname")).sortWithinPartitions(desc("val")) 
//df2.rdd.glom().collect()
 
//3. Take top N per partition. Thus num partitions x 2 in this case. The take(n) is the top n per partition. No OOM.
val rdd2 = df2.rdd.mapPartitions(_.take(2))

//4. Ghastly Row to DF work-arounds.
val schema = new StructType()
  .add(StructField("f", StringType, true))
  .add(StructField("m", StringType, true))
  .add(StructField("l", StringType, true))
  .add(StructField("d", StringType, true))
  .add(StructField("g", StringType, true))
  .add(StructField("v", IntegerType, true))

val df3 = spark.createDataFrame(rdd2, schema)

//5. Sort and take top(n) = 2 and Bob's your uncle. The Reduce after Combine.
df3.sort(col("v").desc).limit(2).show()
```

Returns for top 2 desc:

```
+-------+---+-------+-----+---+--------+
|      f|  m|      l|    d|  g|       v|
+-------+---+-------+-----+---+--------+
|Robert |   |Zeedong|42114|  M|40000000|
| James |   |  Smith|36636|  M|   33000|
+-------+---+-------+-----+---+--------+
```