# What's most efficient way to display first n rows of pyspark dataframe

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

In Pandas everytime I do some operation to a dataframe, I call .head() to see visually what data looks like.

While working with large dataset using pyspark, calling df.show(5) takes a very long time.

After reading about caching and persisting I've tried df.show().cache() hoping that after caching I could display content of df easily like pandas however doesn't seem to improve speed. This is what I've done to measure time. Note time measure was done on small dataset that fits in memory.

```
# w/o cache
%%timeit
df.show()

# with cache 
df.show().cache()
%%timeit  
df.show()

# testing again w/o cache
df.show().uncache() 
%%timeit
df.show()
```

Comment: Have you considered `df.take(n)` or `df.limit(n)` ?

Comment: yeah I usually do df.limit(5).show() or df.limit(5).toPandas() however they seem to take a while as well. Did not try .take() though

Comment: Are you transforming your data? I'm asking because laze transformation characteristic of spark does not apply any transformations unless an action is initiated, so the time it takes might be for applying transformations

Comment: If you are testing on transformations, you could try using `df_sample = df.sample(some fraction of number).cache()` and do transformation of the subset of data instead of the whole large dataset and test.

Comment: This should help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69256388/spark-performant-way-to-find-top-n-values